# Inbox type UI control in BlackBerry 5.0

Tags: blackberry, uicontrol, inbox

I'm looking for an "Inbox-styled" control that we see in BlackBerry device i.e. one row has From, Time and Subject and the entire is selectable. If there is no readily available control, it would of immense help if someone can point to appropriate method.

BlackBerry 5.0 Java API

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[Create a Custom Listfield - Change Highlight Color when Scrolling](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html)" from the berrytutorials blog to learn how to create a `listField` . In the  `drawListRow` method you can get the graphics object and draw the list row as you want.

Comment: thanks! this helps! but it still doesn't solve my problem. I'm using g.drawText("text1", 0, y, 0, -1) to draw the leftmost text. I want to add text2 at the right most of the row. i tried g.drawText("text2", w-text1.length - text2.length, 0, -1) but doesnt work. text2 goes out of the screen. I understand that text2.length is not same as the no of pixels text2 occupies. So, what is the best way to get the x,y position for text to drawn at the right most side of the row?